# Select Picker Problem with bootstrap 4: Multiselect Box Goes Off Screen

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

Below is a complete HTML reproducible example. When using the selectpicker class from bootstrap-select, the live search box flows off to the left in the sidebar when clicking in the box and is not visible in the UI. This did not occur using earlier versions of bootstrap, but I am now migrating to newer versions. I am not able to see the root cause, does anyone else have a suggested fix?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html lang="en"> 
      
    <head> 
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    
    <style> 
        .sidebar { 
            top: 50px; 
            left: 0px; 
            position: sticky; 
        } 
    </style> 
    
    <style>
    body, html {
        height:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    /*
     * Off Canvas sidebar at medium breakpoint
     * --------------------------------------------------
     */
    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    
      .row-offcanvas {
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
      }
    
      .row-offcanvas-left
      .sidebar-offcanvas {
        left: -33%;
      }
    
      .row-offcanvas-left.active {
        left: 33%;
        margin-left: -6px;
      }
    
      .sidebar-offcanvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 33%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    }
    
    /*
     * Off Canvas wider at sm breakpoint
     * --------------------------------------------------
     */
    @media screen and (max-width: 34em) {
      .row-offcanvas-left
      .sidebar-offcanvas {
        left: -45%;
      }
    
      .row-offcanvas-left.active {
        left: 45%;
        margin-left: -6px;
      }
      
      .sidebar-offcanvas {
        width: 45%;
      }
    }
    
    .card {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    
    .card-body .rotate {
        z-index: 8;
        float: right;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .card-body .rotate i {
        color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.15);
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        left: auto;
        right: -10px;
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-44deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-44deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-44deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-44deg);
        transform: rotate(-44deg);
    }
    
    </style>
    </head> 
      
    <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary mb-3">
        <div class="flex-row d-flex">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler mr-2 " data-toggle="offcanvas" title="Toggle responsive left sidebar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="Free Bootstrap 4 Admin Template">Admin Template</a>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="//www.codeply.com">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#myAlert" data-toggle="collapse">Alert</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container-fluid" id="main">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left vh-100">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 sidebar-offcanvas h-100 overflow-auto bg-light pl-0" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sticky-top pl-0 pt-5 mt-3">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Overview</a></li>
    
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Layouts</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Templates</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Themes</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Last Item</a></li>
                    
                    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                      <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
                      <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
                      <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
                    </select>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
    
            <!--/col-->
            <main class="col main pt-5 mt-3 h-100 overflow-auto">
                <h1 class="display-4 d-none d-sm-block">
                Bootstrap Dashboard
                </h1>
                <p class="lead d-none d-sm-block">Plus scrolling sidebar, based on Bootstrap 4</p>
    
                <div class="alert alert-warning fade collapse" role="alert" id="myAlert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> It's free.. this is an example theme.
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 py-2">
                        <div class="card bg-success text-white h-100">
                            <div class="card-body bg-success">
                                <div class="rotate">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <h6 class="text-uppercase">Users</h6>
                                <h1 class="display-4">134</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 py-2">
                        <div class="card text-white bg-danger h-100">
                            <div class="card-body bg-danger">
                                <div class="rotate">
                                    <i class="fa fa-list fa-4x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <h6 class="text-uppercase">Posts</h6>
                                <h1 class="display-4">87</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 py-2">
                        <div class="card text-white bg-info h-100">
                            <div class="card-body bg-info">
                                <div class="rotate">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <h6 class="text-uppercase">Tweets</h6>
                                <h1 class="display-4">125</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 py-2">
                        <div class="card text-white bg-warning h-100">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="rotate">
                                    <i class="fa fa-share fa-4x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <h6 class="text-uppercase">Shares</h6>
                                <h1 class="display-4">36</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/row-->
    
                <hr>
               
    
                <a id="features"></a>
                <hr>
                <p class="lead mt-5">
                    Are you ready for Bootstap 4? It's the 4th generation of this popular responsive framework. Bootstrap 4 will include some interesting 
                    new features such as flexbox, 5 grid sizes (now including xl), cards, `em` sizing, CSS normalization (reboot) and larger font
                    sizes.
                </p>
                <div class="row my-4">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/740x180/bbb/fff?text=..." alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Layouts</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">Flexbox provides simpler, more flexible layout options like vertical centering.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card card-inverse bg-inverse mt-3">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">Flexbox</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Flexbox is now the default, and Bootstrap 4 supports SASS out of the box.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Outline</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead class="thead-inverse">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Label</th>
                                        <th>Header</th>
                                        <th>Column</th>
                                        <th>Data</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,001</td>
                                        <td>responsive</td>
                                        <td>bootstrap</td>
                                        <td>cards</td>
                                        <td>grid</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,002</td>
                                        <td>rwd</td>
                                        <td>web designers</td>
                                        <td>theme</td>
                                        <td>responsive</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,003</td>
                                        <td>free</td>
                                        <td>open-source</td>
                                        <td>download</td>
                                        <td>template</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,003</td>
                                        <td>frontend</td>
                                        <td>developer</td>
                                        <td>coding</td>
                                        <td>card panel</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,004</td>
                                        <td>migration</td>
                                        <td>bootstrap 4</td>
                                        <td>mobile-first</td>
                                        <td>design</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,005</td>
                                        <td>navbar</td>
                                        <td>sticky</td>
                                        <td>jumbtron</td>
                                        <td>header</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,006</td>
                                        <td>collapse</td>
                                        <td>affix</td>
                                        <td>submenu</td>
                                        <td>flexbox</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,007</td>
                                        <td>layout</td>
                                        <td>examples</td>
                                        <td>themes</td>
                                        <td>grid</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,008</td>
                                        <td>migration</td>
                                        <td>bootstrap 4</td>
                                        <td>flexbox</td>
                                        <td>design</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/row-->          
    
            </main>
            <!--/main col-->
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->
    
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
      $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
      });
      
    });
    </script>
    </body>
      
    </html>
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine on desktop width for me, but on phone it shoots up and a bit to the left, is that what you are getting too? < using latest version of Google Chrome on Windows 10

Comment: Even on my desktop (using multiple different machines and screen sizes), it shoots off to the left off screen for me. Using both Chrome and Mozilla I observe the same behavior.

Comment: Have you tried the `dropdownAlignRight` option? [Link](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#core-options)

Comment: Good suggestion. Added that to the HTML as ```<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-dropdown-align-right="true">``` but still doesn't align to the right in my broswer(s).

Comment: Adding the class ```dropright``` as in ```<select class="selectpicker dropright" data-live-search="true">``` does push things to the right, but the text doesn't flow far enough to see the entire text. Seems to be cut off by the sidebar and not sure if anyone sees a fix so it expands completely?